# Add Label and Custom CSS on `Primefaces:dashboard` Component

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, dashboard

I am working on https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/dashboard.xhtml

Here i want to modify the UI and apply CSS

- Set label of boards (Todo, In-progress, Done, Block)
- Apply custom CSS on each dashboard

I've tried using, but it is apply on all dashboards

```
.ui-dashboard-column::before{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: navy;
  content: "Todo List. ";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your procedure defining the `DashBoardModel` you can set a `styleClass` per column:

```
DefaultDashboardColumn column1 = new DefaultDashboardColumn();
// ...
column1.setStyleClass("todo")
model.addColumn(column1);
```

Then use this `styleClass` with your css selector:

```
.ui-dashboard-column.todo::before{
 ...
}
```

**see also**

- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

Comment: This is not as overriding default PrimeFaces CSS, `DefaultDashboardColumn` works for me, further i can add using `context: "LABEL OF BOARD"` thanks